# Internal Salesforce.com Error while executing batch class

Tags: apex, batch, chatter, contentdocument, contentdocumentlink

I want to create a batch class for the ContentdDocumentLink. I am getting records in the querylocator. But the execute() method is not working. In the debug logs also I am not able to trace any problem. The debug log is showing **Internal Salesforce.com Error**. May I know is there any limitations as such to the ContentDocumentLink object?

Here is the code sample:

```
global class CommunityActivityJob implements Database.Batchable<sObject>,Database.AllowsCallouts ,Database.Stateful {
global Database.QueryLocator start(Database.BatchableContext BC) {
List<String> linked = new List<String>();
linked.add('00528000000M2xj');
   String query = 'Select Id, ContentDocumentId, LinkedEntityId, ShareType, Visibility from ContentDocumentLink Where LinkedEntityId In :linked ';
    System.debug('===START==='+Database.query(query));
    return Database.getQueryLocator(query);
}
 global void execute(Database.BatchableContext BC, List<sObject> scope) {
    System.Debug('===INSIDE EXECUTE==='+scope);
    }
global void finish(Database.BatchableContext BC) {
    System.debug('===Inside Finish===');
}
```

Here is the Debug logs result:

> 02:15:35.0 (368461)|EXECUTION_STARTED 02:15:35.0
>   (372197)|CODE_UNIT_STARTED|[EXTERNAL]|01p2800000FdNp2|CommunityActivityJob
>   02:15:35.0 (3586564)|HEAP_ALLOCATE|[EXTERNAL]|Bytes:4 02:15:35.0
>   (25452249)|FATAL_ERROR|Internal Salesforce.com Error 02:15:35.25
>   (25736049)|CUMULATIVE_LIMIT_USAGE 02:15:35.25
>   (25736049)|LIMIT_USAGE_FOR_NS|(default)|   Number of SOQL queries: 0
>   out of 200   Number of query rows: 0 out of 50000   Number of SOSL
>   queries: 0 out of 20   Number of DML statements: 0 out of 150   Number
>   of DML rows: 0 out of 10000   Maximum CPU time: 0 out of 60000
>   Maximum heap size: 0 out of 12000000   Number of callouts: 0 out of 0 
>   Number of Email Invocations: 0 out of 10   Number of future calls: 0
>   out of 0   Number of queueable jobs added to the queue: 0 out of 1
>   Number of Mobile Apex push calls: 0 out of 10
>
> 02:15:35.25 (25736049)|CUMULATIVE_LIMIT_USAGE_END
>
> 02:15:35.0 (25817145)|CODE_UNIT_FINISHED|CommunityActivityJob
>   02:15:35.0 (26892816)|EXECUTION_FINISHED

Thanks for your response.